# How to add unit tests to my fluent validation class?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, fluentvalidation

I have a c# model class (Address.cs) which looks like this...

```
namespace myProject.Models
{
    [Validator(typeof(AddressValidator))]
    public class Address
    {
        public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
        public string PostCode { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and I have a validator class (AddressValidator.cs) which looks like this...

```
namespace myProject.Validation
{
    public class AddressValidator : AbstractValidator<Address>
    {
        public AddressValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.PostCode).NotEmpty().WithMessage("The Postcode is required");
            RuleFor(x => x.AddressLine1).MaximumLength(40).WithMessage("The first line of the address must be {MaxLength} characters or less");
        }
    }
}
```

And I'm wondering, how I can add unit tests for my validator class, such that I can test that, for example, 'Address Line 1' takes up to 40 characters?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do that with something like the following (this uses xunit, adjust to your preferred framework)

```
public class AddressValidationShould
{
  private AddressValidator Validator {get;}
  public AddressValidationShould()
  {
    Validator = new AddressValidator();
  }

  [Fact]
  public void NotAllowEmptyPostcode()
  {
    var address = new Address(); // You should create a valid address object here
    address.Postcode = string.empty; // and then invalidate the specific things you want to test
    Validator.Validate(address).IsValid.Should().BeFalse();
  }
}
```

... and obviously create other tests to cover the other things that should/shouldn't be allowed. Such as `AddressLine1` being over 40 being invalid, and 40 or less being valid.

Answer (score 1):

With MSTest you can write

```
[TestMethod]
public void NotAllowEmptyPostcode()
{
    // Given
    var address = new Address(); // You should create a valid address object here
    address.Postcode = string.empty; // invalidate the specific property

    // When
    var result = validator.Validate(address);
    
    // Then (Assertions)
    Assert.That(result.Errors.Any(o => o.PropertyName== "Postcode"));
}
```